# Python String to Hex Bytes

Tags: python, struct, hex, byte

In python, I'm trying to convert a string literal to it's hexadecimal 4 byte equivalent. Here's an example of what I'm doing:

```
import struct
struct.pack("<i", int("08050030", 16))
>>'0\x00\x05\x08'
```

Why is the output rendering like this? I would expect `\x30\x00\x05\x08`?

Comment: because `'0' == '\x30'`. If the character can be represented as a ascii character, it is displayed as the chracter instead of `\xOO` form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would probably be surprised if the REPL did this

```
>>> "hello"
'\x68\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f'
```

Luckily it doesn't. printable characters are printed as themselves. unprintable characters use shortcuts such as `'\n'` and when none is available, the last resort is to use the hex notation.

It's perfectly acceptable to use hex encoding anywhere in your literals

```
>>> '\x30\x00\x05\x08'
'0\x00\x05\x08'
```

It's just not Python's preference to use them for display.